# WinDbg fail to find offset of main function

Tags: windbg, fuzzing

Hey everyone I try to find the main function offset in WinDbg, I have load all the symbols but it still not work.

the error I get is : `**'*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Program.exe(name of the program)**`'.

thanks :).

Comment: I try to write in the command line this function : ' x Program!main '

Answer (score 1):

[unable to verify checksum is not an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629962/unable-to-verify-checksum-for-exe/25638480#25638480) and that error has got nothing to do with the unable to find main

may be you are loading a gui binary which doesn't have main but has **WinMain**
may be it is a unicode version with **wWinMain** 
may be it is a binary which was compiled with /Entry compiler switch

try checking with wildcards

```
x module!*main*
```

may be it would list one of the above variants of main

or use the $exentry Pseudo Register and step around from there

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that problem by load the symbols in the right way..