# In windbg, what can cause the message “WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mydll.dll”?

Tags: debugging, symbols, windbg, dump

I have a *User Mini Dump File* and I get in the output of `!analyze -v` this warning:

```
"WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mydll.dll"
```

Symbol search path is: `cache*E:\sym;srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;E:\sym\myapp`

and `mydll.pdb` and `mydll.dll` are both in `E:\sym\myapp`.
I got `mydll.pdb` and `mydll.dll` straight from my build folder in Visual Studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629962/unable-to-verify-checksum-for-exe/25638480#25638480

Comment: @blabb thank you very much! Stackoverflow did not suggest me that question.